# Animated pop-up like on wunderlist.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I've came across [wunderlist.com](http://www.wunderlist.com) site and just fell in love with the zoom-like pop-up they have on the image just beneath the header "Learn more about Wunderlist".
I'd love to implement something like this on my site.

Can somebody tell me how this is done? I tried to reverse-engineer, but with no luck :)
I'm not hoping for the whole ready code, but maybe some guidelines on how to achieve this with CSS/jQuery.

Or maybe you know some jQuery plugin that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using all CSS.  Pretty simple really..  I would code a full js fiddle example for you but I don't have the time, so instead I will list out the different elements you need and how they interact.

1. First the large image is just a div with a background image with set
   dimensions.
2. The circular images themselves are generated from one large image containing all of the circles in one spot, this is called a sprite.  The circles are just div's with background images and background positioning to position the correct circle inside the box from the sprite image.
3. The text boxes themselves are also div's with a standard H2 and P tags for the text.
4. Everything is absolute positioned in order to achieve the proper layout.
5. The small circles are div's with `:hover` states that are absolute positioned over their respective targeted areas.
6. The animation on `:hover` is achieved by the use of css3 transition and css3 transforms.

This should get you started.

Comment if you have questions.

Had some time to have some fun: http://khill.mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate/fun-experiment-mh/

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at two main aspects: 
Open up your inspector tool of choice and look at what happens to `body.login .feature` 
...more specifically, look at what happens to its `transform: scale` and `opacity` values upon :hover.

Hint: the transition is mainly on them.

Still in your inspector, change the scale to (1) and the opacity to 1. How it smoothly gets from one state to the other is dictated by the `transition` property.

This isn't meant to tell you exactly how to achieve it, but to get you on your way :)

Comment: Thx, it did get me on my way indeed!
One more thing - how is graying-out the rest of the page done?

Comment: When you look in the #welcome-screen node, you'll find a div with an id of #overlay. Initially, its opacity is 0. Upon activating the any of the others with :hover, its opacity transitions up to 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard actually. The Wunderlist team has even made it easier. They have a large sprite image with the zoomed images cropped and ready with rounded corners, borders and shadows. You can see it here: https://wunderlist2.s3.amazonaws.com/179510ff7c929bfcc6e9819f3c2539baca5d3325/images/welcome-screen.png

What you do is on mouseover you show a half transparent black background (can be position: fixed with full width and height). Then you create a element with the sprite as the background image (even better, have a class ready in your css and append it to your newly created element). Set position to the position of the hovered element.

When added to the dom animate the transform scale of the element (starting with something like  scale(.24) as they do).

Answer (score 0):

Well since you tried reverse engineering. I'll try and guide you along that path.

There is only one div with id **overlay** which is changes it's place & content, on hover of any div with class **feature**. Work your way further from their [app js](https://wunderlist2.s3.amazonaws.com/96005445b6d83819437e1584ffd81b4e1de63635/app.js), it's not minified.

The content of the popup in this case is an [image](https://wunderlist2.s3.amazonaws.com/179510ff7c929bfcc6e9819f3c2539baca5d3325/images/welcome-screen.png) moved to different positions.